# Cannot determine, what this partw error message is aiming at

Tags: plotting, bugs, piecewise, discontinuity

**Bug introduced in 7.0, persisting through 13.2.**

---

So i am trying to plot the magnetic vector field surrounding a "flat conducting cable" (don't know the proper english expression).

This is the "code" (there are some constants in the analytic formulas, which I have excluded for the sake of clarity):

```
 VectorPlot[{Piecewise[{{ArcTan[y/(x + 3)] - (Pi - ArcTan[y/(x - 3)]), 

 Abs[x] < 3}},

 ArcTan[y/(x + 3)] - ArcTan[y/(x - 3)]],

 Log[Sqrt[(y^2 + (x + 3)^2)]/Sqrt[(y^2 + (x - 3)^2)]]},

 {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

The error message I get is the following:

Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>

I am not sure whether Piecewise can be used with VectorPlot at all since I haven't managed to find a syntactic, so that is probably where the problem lies. (I have managed to plot the separate functions, basically I am experiencing problems implementing Piecewise into the code.)

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's a pity the question didn't receive enough attention. This turns out to be a bug: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/286918/1871

Answer (score 2):

A vector plot needs two components:

```
 VectorPlot[
   Piecewise[
  {
   {{ArcTan[y/(x + 3)] - (Pi - ArcTan[y/(x - 3)]), y}, 
    Abs[x] < 3},
   {{ArcTan[y/(x + 3)] - ArcTan[y/(x - 3)], y}, 
     Log[Sqrt[(y^2 + (x + 3)^2)]/Sqrt[(y^2 + (x - 3)^2)]]}
   }
            ],
   {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}
           ]
```

[image]

Of course, you will need to include the proper formula for the $x$ and the $y$ components of your vector in the ranges you state.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it has left me even more confused as I don't see how it fits with the syntax for the Piecewise or VectorPlot functions at all ...
First let me ask you why did you put the y at the end of the first two formulas and nothing at the end of the last one? (actually the first two were defining x in ranges bordered by 3 and -3 and the third one was for y, but that doesn't really matter)

Comment: @HudPesjan A `VectorPlot` is (of course) a plot of *vectors*, which here must have two components.  Your original posting had just a scalar (one component).  My answer included *two* components (placed within `{}`), and I arbitrarily introduced a second component whose value was $y$.  As I stated, *you* must write *both* components of your vector in your function.  The conditional statement, however, can be one-dimensional, as indeed all of the above are.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense, but I am not sure I understand what is going on in the code. My questions would be firstly: Have you included both, the x and y components inside the Piecewise function and wether it is neccesesary to do so?
And secondly: If I have understood correctly, what you have written inside the Piecewise function is:
{
     {component (for x?), y},
        condition (for x?)},
{
     {component (for y?), y},
        condition (for y?)},
It kinda doesn't look like the suggested Piecewise syntax, so I don't see what you really did there.

Comment: @HudPesjan It is indeed necessary to include a list of two elements as your function—the $x$ and the $y$ components of your vector field.  I just put in a simple $y$... you must determine the formula for the $x$ component and $y$ component of your vector.  The *condition* which determines which vector function to use must evaluate to `True` or `False`, and thus can be a function of one variable, two variables, or whatever.